# Who are the Gibberlings Three?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

I'm looking for the full quote from Baldur's Gate II, which is the answer to this question.
This is a quote that is said by a character after the party encounters a family of dwarfs or gnomes, if I remember correctly. Would appreciate a screenshot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question is asked by Uncle Gerhardt, after you go down to the cellar in Jansen Home:

> Who in the blazes are ye? Small noses, rancid smell... hmm.. be ye gibberlings?

The quote you are looking for is:

> "We are the Gibberlings Three. As merry a band as you ever did see."

[image: 3 gibberlings]